# Can't get WordPress hook to fire inside embedded class

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to build some nice metabox functionality with some oop.

I have my main DazSEO class, which inside contains a Metabox Class.

When I set WordPress save data hooks up inside the metabox class, they won't fire, but when I set them up from the root class, they will.

Is using hooks inside embedded classes incompatible with the WordPress hook system?

Any help would be appreciated here as I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is the issue here, I guess it is some object scope issue for the wp engine, but I am not convinced.
    class DazSEO {
    public static $plugins = array();

```
public $metaBox;    

public function __construct() {

    add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'adminInit') );
    add_action('init', array($this, 'init'));
}

public function adminInit() {
    $this->setupMetaBox();
}    

public function setupMetaBox() {   
    if( $pagenow === 'term.php' ) { // returns true

        if( isset($_GET['taxonomy']) ) { 
            $term = get_term( $_GET['tag_ID'], $_GET['taxonomy'], OBJECT );

            require_once('admin\metabox\TermMetaBox.php'); 
            $this->metaBox = new TermMetabox( $_GET['taxonomy'] ); // confirmed this does fire

            DazSEO::$mode = 'term';
            DazSEO::$wpID = $_GET['tag_ID'];
            DazSEO::$typeName = $_GET['taxonomy'];
        } 
    }
}    
}

class TermMetabox extends MetaBoxBase {
  private $_taxonomy;

  public function __construct(string $taxonomy) {        
    if( strlen($taxonomy) === 0 ) { echo 'no taxonomy passed'; exit(); }

    $this->_taxonomy = $taxonomy;

    add_action(  $this->_taxonomy . '_edit_form', array($this, 'buildMetaBox') );       

    add_action('edit_terms', array($this, 'onTermSave')); // SETUP TERM SAVE     
}


  public function loadHooks() {

}


// NOT BEING CALLED
public function onTermSave(int $term_id) {

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_REQUEST, 1) . '</pre>'; exit(); 

    if( $this->onSaveChecks($term_id) ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach(DazSEO::$plugins as $plugin) {
        $plugin->onTermSave($term_id, $_REQUEST);
    }
}
}
```

The TermMetabox:: onTermSave never gets called

If this is called from the root class (DazSEO), and I move the save method in there too it works...

```
add_action('edit_terms', array($this, 'onTermSave'));
```

But it's messy design like that.

This plugin is initialized like this...

```
$dazSEO = new DazSEO();
$wpCleanHeader = new RemoveWPHeaderJunk();
$dazSEO->loadPlugin($wpCleanHeader);
```

Comment: In `setupMetaBox()`, what is `$pagenow`, and the `$pagenow === 'term.php'` may have never evaluated to `true`, hence your `TermMetabox` class didn't get instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Yes the statement does evaluate true, I have some debug code there which is firing that I removed to keep the example here lean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `$pagenow` is a [global WordPress admin variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Admin_Globals), then these may answer the question: (the PHP files mentioned below are saved in `wp-admin`)

1. When you visit the `term.php` (i.e. the taxonomy term edit) page, `$_GET['taxonomy']` and `$_GET['tag_ID']` are set/available by default (and required by WordPress for determining which term you're editing). Therefore `isset($_GET['taxonomy'])` evaluates to `true`.
2. However, in your `TermMetabox` class constructor, you are hooking `TermMetabox::onTermSave()` to the `edit_terms` action which is (again, by default) not fired on the `term.php` page.
3. The taxonomy edit form on `term.php` is coming from `edit-tag-form.php`, where the opening `<form>` tag looks like:

   ```
   <form name="edittag" id="edittag" method="post" action="edit-tags.php" ...>
   ```

   and it contains the following hidden `input` fields:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="editedtag"/> <- the action
   <input type="hidden" name="tag_ID" ...>
   <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy" ...>
   ```

   So as you can see, the form is to be submitted using the `POST` method to `edit-tags.php` with the action `editedtag`.
4. On `edit-tags.php`, if the action is `editedtag`, [`wp_update_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/) would be called and you'd eventually brought back to `term.php`. And if you don't know yet, `wp_update_term()` [fires](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2763) the `edit_terms` action.

So with your existing code, you can fix it like so, where I'm checking if `$pagenow` is `edit-tags.php`, and that I use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`:

```
public function setupMetaBox() {
    // global $pagenow; // I used this when testing.
    if( $pagenow === 'edit-tags.php' ) {

        if( isset($_POST['taxonomy']) ) {
            ...

            require_once('admin\metabox\TermMetaBox.php');
            $this->metaBox = new TermMetabox( $_POST['taxonomy'] );

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, instead of the `$pagenow === 'edit-tags.php'` check, you can use the `load-edit-tags.php` action, like so:

- `DazSEO::adminInit()`:

  ```
  public function adminInit() {
      add_action( 'load-edit-tags.php', array( $this, 'setupMetaBox' ) );
  }
  ```
- `DazSEO::setupMetaBox()`:

  ```
  public function setupMetaBox() {
      if( isset($_POST['taxonomy']) ) {
          ...

          require_once('admin\metabox\TermMetaBox.php');
          $this->metaBox = new TermMetabox( $_POST['taxonomy'] );

          ...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even consider the middle step of where the form is submitted to. My Metabox class design would not work as I am fighting with the wordpress api when to instantiate it to get it to work. So I made a SaveData class and separated the data saving into there instead. Now I can move on with the job.

Comment: That's awesome, and I'm glad I could help you. :) Btw, when I said "The taxonomy edit form on `term.php`", I actually meant "The taxonomy *term* edit form on `term.php`". Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you, as far as I understand - taxonomies are like categories for terms "grouping" them, as normal wp categories group posts, but two separate apis within the WordPress core.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the grouping, and in a taxonomy (e.g. the standard/built-in post categories and tags), you can have one to many groups which WordPress call them as "terms". However, although post categories and tags have special/built-in wrapper functions, these functions actually use the same API - e.g. `get_category()` and `get_tag()` which both use `get_term()` - and you can find this function and the other taxonomy/term functions in `wp-includes/taxonomy.php`. Refer to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) if you need more info about taxonomies. :)